# re-initiate a jQuery plug-in after dynamically inserting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I have a jQuery tabs plug-in which works well... However I have a lightbox (also dynamicaly generated) that allows users to choose content which then gets shown in tabs.

This works fine if the user chooses content, leaves the page and comes back.. however i want the tabs to work as soon as the user finishes selecting content.

I have tried the usual .delegate() tags, but which event do I attach them to? I have tried doing it on the 'save' button on the lightbox but as this is also dynamically generated it doesn't appear to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which tabs plugin are you using?

Comment: Any chance for a jsfiddle so we can see what exactly you're working with?

Comment: It is not really possible to put it into a JSfiddle.

Basically I have the tabs plugin included on the page so any tabs that are there on the page to start with function correctly.

If the user edits the page using the editor that I have built into a lightbox (so this is still on the same page) and then add's another set of tabs - those new tabs do not then work until the page is refreshed.

Comment: this one? https://github.com/ginader/Accessible-Tabs/

Comment: that's the one! sorry, I should have included a link

Comment: you will probably need to remove all old tabs along with their content and re-create them again, which is close to reloading the whole page... but you can probably do this via AJAX, so user waits on the same page